# Repeat random, unique sampling of k values n times

Tags: matlab, random

In Matlab, I would like to generate a matrix with 4 random, unique samples (out of 10) 7 times.
In order to avoid a for-loop, I thought I could just repeat my data and use `datasample` from Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox on the first dimension. But it always chooses *the same 4 values* from each column, so this is kind of useless.

Consider the following MWE:

```
randomData  = [50.29; 47.72; 48.38; 48.02; 44.23; 47.17; 48.19; 49.11; 50.44; 53.40];

numOfReps               = 7;
numOfSamples            = 4;

randomDataRepMatrix     = randomData*ones(1, numOfReps);

s           = RandStream('mlfg6331_64');
y           = datasample(s, randomDataRepMatrix, numOfSamples, 'Replace', false);
```

Even without the `RandStream` part, I get the same results...

Any idea? Or do I need to use the for-loop after all?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html#bs10l6i-10): You can use `randi` or `randperm` to generate indices for random sampling with or without replacement, respectively. However, `datasample` can be more convenient to use because it samples directly from your data.

Comment: “In order to avoid a for loop”. You should always implement the for loop if vectorization is not trivial, and evaluate the result. Is this a bottleneck in your code? Then try to optimize it. Otherwise, you are just wasting time, which is the opposite of optimizing. Loops are not inherently slow in MATLAB, this perception is a holdover from 15 years ago, before they introduced a JIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `datasample` or `randsample` can produce several sets of samples in one go. Here's a "manual" way to do it (not necessarily faster than using `datasample` with a loop):

```
[~, ind] = sort(rand(numel(randomData), numOfReps)); % each column is a permutation
ind = ind(1:numOfSamples,:); % keep only the first values in each column
y = randomData(ind); % index into data
```